# Dense sets in $\Bbb{R}^2$ with rational distance

Tags: nt.number-theory, mg.metric-geometry, open-problems

We call a subset $S\subset \Bbb{R}^2$ *rationally distanced* if all $s_1,s_2 \in S$ have rational Euclidean distance.

The [Erdos-Ulam conjecture](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Ulam_problem) asks if there is a dense subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$ which is rationally distanced. Inspired by this, I came up with the following toy problem.

A subset $X \subset \Bbb{R}^2$ is *good* if there exists a rationally distanced $S \subset \Bbb{R}^2\setminus \overline{X}$ such that each $x\in X$ is a limit point of $S$.

I have three questions:

1. Is $[0,1]\times \{0\}$ good?
2. If $[0,1] \times \{0\} $ is not good, does this imply a negative solution to the Erdos-Ulam conjecture? (i.e. can we show that no rationally distanced subset $S$ of $\Bbb{R}^2$ can intersect all possible line segments in $\Bbb{R}^2$)
3. Is there an infinite good set that is not a subset of a straight line? (to avoid trivial examples like $\{n+\sqrt{2}:n\in \Bbb{Z}\}\times \{0\}$ for which $\Bbb{Q}\times\{0\}$ is a solution)

**Edit:**
Question 2 is straight-forward. Obviously, for $S$ to intersect each of the line segments $\{[0,1]\times \{\alpha\}:\alpha \in \Bbb{R}\}$, we must have $S$ be uncountable. Originally I saw this much, but didn't know how to deal with the distance function not being injective.

For $S$ to be dense in $\Bbb{R}^2$, there must distinct $s_1,s_2,s_3 \in S$ which are not collinear. We then have that the map $\phi:x \mapsto (|x-s_1|,|x-s_2|,|x-s_3|)$ is a injection from $\Bbb{R}^2$ to $\Bbb{R}^3$. The uncountability of $S$ then immediately gives that $\phi(S) \not\subseteq \Bbb{Q}^3$, hence there exists some $i \in \{1,2,3\}, s^* \in S$ such that $|s_i-s^*|$ is irrational, making $S$ not rationally distanced.

**Edit 2:** Wojowu pointed out that since there are rationally distanced subsets of the unit circle, we can get infinite good sets that are not subsets of a line. So Question 3 as stated here is resolved in the positive. I'm still interested to see other constructions, but I will ask about that in a future post, after I've collected my thoughts.

Comment: A conjecture can't "ask", but "predicts".

Comment: Do you have an example that you know to be an infinite good set?

Comment: @LSpice a rather trivial example is $\{(0,n+\sqrt{2}): n \in \Bbb{Z}\}$. So I guess my third problem needs reworking to avoid one dimension sets $X$.

Comment: There are dense rationally distanced subsets of the unit circle, take for instance the complex points $(\frac{3}{5}+\frac{4}{5}i)^{2n},n\in\mathbb Z$. Any closed subset of its complement in the unit circle will answer 3.

Comment: A rationally distanced set has to be countable so that trivially answers 2.

Comment: @Wojowu I was aware vaguely aware of the circle result already. but since any infinite closed subset of the unit circle will be dense somewhere, I assumed that this complicated things significantly. if it your idea still works in spite of this, I'd be interested to see it explained in more detail, I can't quite see it yet.

Comment: "any infinite closed subset of the unit circle will be dense somewhere" is wrong. Think of Cantor set, but bend it so it fits in a circle. In general, any uncountable subset of R^2 contains an uncountable compact subset, by Cantor-Bendixson theorem.

Comment: oh! you're quite right, silly me. I guess there was a reason to specify unbounded, I just didn't realize it yet.

Comment: No one knows whether there are even eight points in the plane, no three in a line, no four on a circle, all at rational distances from each other – the current record is seven points (see under "integral heptagon").

Comment: @Wojowu: "any uncountable subset of R^2 contains an uncountable compact subset" is wrong. It's true if you add "Borel" at the beginning, so your point remains, but counterexamples (known as "Bernstein sets") can be constructed using AC. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_set

Comment: I don't understand your comments on question 2. A subset of $\mathbb R^2 \setminus [0,1] \times \{0\}$ doesn't have to be uncountable to have $[0,1] \times \{0\}$ included in its closure. For example, $\{ (1/2^n,k/2^nn) :\, 0 \leq k \leq n \in \mathbb N\}$ is a countable set with boundary $[0,1] \times \{0\}$ (but not rationally distanced, of course).

Comment: @WillBrian Ah of course, Cantor-Bendixson is only valid for closed sets. I should have appealed to some other result. As for question 2, note that if $[0,1]\times\{0\}$ is not good, then neither is any interval in the plane. But if there is a dense rationally distanced subset of the plane, then every interval not containing any of those points is good.

Comment: @YCor Have you never made such a mistake?

Comment: @WillSawin Of course I did. Possibly if I don't do some mistake it's because somebody once helped me by telling me. Thanks to them!

Comment: @YCor Some ways of pointing this (or any other mistake) out are more pleasant than others. I was once not so good at pointing out mistakes politely, but people have pointed it out to me, and now I am trying to be better.

Comment: @WillSawin my tone was meant to be neutral, I wouldn't feel comfortable in flourishing it with inessential rhetoric words (although I sometimes feel forced to do so).

Comment: That's fair! The only issue is that a neutral tone over the Internet can feel cold or even cruel. When the information is necessary, this could be worth it, but in this case... Something like "Did you mean the Erdős-Ulam problem?" would be a bit better, without any "rhetorical flourish".

Comment: It sounds like you solved it yourself, based on the edits and the comments. I think it would be appropriate to post an answer summarizing that thinking, so it doesn't linger unanswered.